# Compiler have found Unexpected characters

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

I am working on React project.
There is a component that I'm importing to the main component.

It has traditional `import React from 'react';` line.
But suddenly compiler display a message about SyntaxError. It said that it found 'Unexpected character: '?'.

And a place that it found this character is in line 1:
`'?''?'import React from 'react';`

Fortunately, I solved it but restarting compiler.
But I want to know why did this happened? Is there any solutions that will prevent such errors in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's at the very beginning of the file, it might be the byte-order mark; some editors automatically insert it when you edit a file. What editor do you use to make changes? Did you recently open it using anything else?

Comment: Visual Studio Code. But than again, why did it worked after restaring compiler?

Comment: I also had to do that. It has to do something with the compiler putting some bytes on the start of file. Remember, always restart the VS code if something like this happen in future. It does vierd things like this sometime.